# Why  doesn't VS2010 have Crystal Reports?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, oracle, reporting

I've been using CrystalReports since VS2008. Why is it missing in VS2010? Is there any specific reason why MS doesn't want it anymore?
If not CrystalReports, which reporting tool would be the primary one for VS2010(as default plug-in)? I don't have much of an idea about SSRS. Is it DB-independent?

Is SSRS a replacement to CR?

Comment: The company was bought out by SAP just before VS2008 shipped.  They have a very different marketing strategy, no free version anymore.

Comment: Hans - there is a free download for VS2010.  See the link in the answer which I just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SSRS 2008 R1, SSRS can almost do anything Crystal Reports can do. In addition, charting and mapping in SSRS is better than Crystal Report. Crystal Reports still has some advantages over SSRS, such as performance, accurate pagination, and better usability in report design, but these advantages are becoming slim, and lots of companies are migrating their Crystal Reports to SSRS.

Answer (score 2):

You can get Crystal Reports for VS2010 for free, but you have to download and install it separately.  Get it from [here](http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/us2_default.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft is leaning heavily toward SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) for reporting out of applications written in its tools. As someone with considerable stripes in the Crystal/Business Objects environment, its a welcome alternative. Given its name, I think it's probably apparent it's heavily tied to SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Reporting Services is the reporting tool of choice for Microsoft.  While Reporting Services is certainly slanted towards use with SQL Server. It is possible to use other databases with it via ODBC (we use to use it with some Informix reports long ago). The client components for both Webforms and Winforms in VS2010 work great.

Comment: Is SSRS a total-replacement for CR?

Comment: From a functionality perspective, I would say yes,  from a product perspective,  nothing is preventing you from continuing to use Crystal Reports, it is just no longer included as part of VS.